# Undefined index with jtable post

Tags: php, jquery, html

table load

```
$('#searchVehicleDesc').button().click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#vehicleLogsTable').jtable('load', {
        plate: $('input[name=vehicle_service_search]').val(),
        date1: $('input[name=searchDate1]').val(),
        date2: $('input[name=searchDate2]').val()
    });
```

php

```
<?PHP
include("db.classes.php");
$g = new DB();
$g->connection();

        $term ="";
        $d1 ="";
        $d2 = "";

        if(isset($_POST['plate']) && isset($_POST['date1']) && isset($_POST['date2']))
        {
            $term = $_POST["plate"];
            $da1 = $_POST["date1"];
            $da2 = $_POST["date2"];
            $g->getAllDesc($term, $da1, $da2);
        }

        else
        {
// line 20      $term = $_POST["plate"];
// line 21      $d1 = $_POST["date1"];
// line 22      $d2 = $_POST["date2"];
            $g->getAllDesc($term, $d1, $d2);
        }   

$g->close();
?>
```

I need to pass the three data to query it but im getting an **Undefined index** error in lines **20, 21, 22** what seems to be wrong here?

Comment: What does $_POST contain? You can use var_dump to output what it contains. And I'm pretty sure you want to remove name= in your javascript

Comment: if 'IF' condition failed means you dont have values in `POST` then how can you ge the POST values in ELSE PART?

Comment: @user790454 so ill go with else if(!isset) ?

Comment: the if condition is checking whether the POST values are empty or not, if empty then it'll go to else part so in else you have to print something like please enter values or any other thing you  want to do when the values are empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with checking it first

```
$term = isset($_POST["plate"]) && !empty($_POST["plate"]) ? $_POST["plate"] : null;
```

now if the post doesn't have those fields, you wont run into errors

Comment: what is this going to do exactly?

Comment: if plate in $_POST variable is set and not empty, assign it to `$term`, otherwise, assign null to it